# Creating the 'next' button based on another activity

Tags: java, android

I am making a drawing app. I have two files : 'CatList_Activity.java' and 'Draw_Activity.java'. CatList_Activity is the page with the menu where all the images are displayed, and by clicking on one (method 'onItemClick') it sends me to the page Draw_Activity and displays that image, id being the attribute 'position' in the override method. What I want to do is to create the 'next' button (via imageView with onClickListener) in Draw_Activity, which will straight away send me to the next image. My guess would be to somehow increment 'position' value in CatList_Activity file, but I am not sure how to do it

CatList_Activity.java

```
public class CatList_Activity extends ActionBarActivity {
    GridView grid;
    private String[] arrImagesStrings;
    String Foldername;
    CatListAdapter adapter;
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.catlist_activity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)
                this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.lsv_catlist);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Foldername = i.getStringExtra("Folder");

        arrImagesStrings = listAssetFiles(Foldername);
        adapter = new CatListAdapter(CatList_Activity.this, R.layout.catlist_item, arrImagesStrings, Foldername);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+selectedImagePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Log.e("name", ""+Foldername+"/"+arrImagesStrings[position]);
                Intent intentdraw = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Draw_Activity.class);
                intentdraw.putExtra("Folder", Foldername + "/" + arrImagesStrings[position]);
                startActivity(intentdraw);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Draw_Activity.java

```
public class Draw_Activity extends Activity {

    private PaintView pv;
    protected View layout;
    protected int progress;
    protected Dialog dialog;
    protected Dialog textdialog;
    private String[] arrImagesStrings;
    protected float stroke = 6;
    int postion;
    private String fileName;
    private int ColorAh = Color.BLACK;
    String Foldername;
    RelativeLayout re;
    private AdView mAdView;
    ImageView img_next;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawpic_activity);

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        re = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rell);
        img_next = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_next);

        this.fileName = null;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.pv = new PaintView(this);
        re.addView(pv);
        //setContentView(this.pv);
        this.pv.togglePencil(true);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Foldername = i.getStringExtra("Folder");


        img_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ???
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your CatList_Activity, change

```
Intent intentdraw=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Draw_Activity.class);
    intentdraw.putExtra("Folder", Foldername+"/"+arrImagesStrings[position]);
```

to

```
Intent intentdraw=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Draw_Activity.class);
    intentdraw.putExtra("FolderName", Foldername);
    intentdraw.putExtra("position", position);
    intentdraw.putExtra("images", arrImagesStrings);
```

In your Draw_Activity, handle onClick to increment the position and get the desired path.

```
Foldername=i.getStringExtra("FolderName");
position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);
images = i.getStringArrayExtra("images");
path = Foldername + "/" + images[position];
```

Comment: Could you post the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Make list of images ....    Do something like this

```
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.slider_list);

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i < menutitles.length; i++) {
        RowItem items = new RowItem(menutitles[i], menuIcons.getResourceId(
```